# How to run a Google Sheets App Script, and if there is an error, then call Spreadsheet function IMPORTXML() instead to populate the cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

To get the price of bitcoin and other cryptocurrencies into my Google Sheets spreadsheet, I use this function:

```
=importJSON("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&ids=bitcoin","0.current_price")
```

where importJSON is a Google App Script provided by coingecko (see https://blog.coingecko.com/import-coingecko-cryptocurrency-data-into-google-sheets/ )

This works fine for a few lookups, but if the spreadsheet has many cryptocurrencies, a whole bunch of them will say "Error: Exceed maximum execution time (line 0)."

[see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/berHh.png)

Is it possible to detect this error, and if there is an error, call this function instead:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin","//div[@class='priceValue___11gHJ']")
```

The problem is that this is a Google Sheets function and I don't know how to call it from inside the Google Apps script inside the catch(err) code block.

[See picture #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjYcr.png)

Comment: Could I suggest an alternative? This service returns crypto prices cached on Cloudflare without the need for any parsing, example `=IMPORTDATA("https://cryptoprices.cc/BTC/")`

Comment: this is great!  thanks @Pedro

Comment: @pedro your solution worked great for a few quotes, but when I am trying to pull lots of quotes and running into errors, this is a problem with Google Sheets and not the website.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69328506/importdata-gets-lots-of-errors-because-i-am-trying-to-load-many-cells-for-stock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can do it wiht [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en)

Sample formula:

```
=IFERROR(importJSON("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&ids=bitcoin","0.current_price"),IMPORTXML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin","//div[@class='priceValue___11gHJ']"))
```