# IMPORTDATA gets lots of errors because I am trying to load many cells for stock quotes

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet with 220 'importdata' functions where each one is pulling a stock quote off a website. The function is just a simple:

```
importdata("http://<URL>/"&A2)
```

where A2 contains the symbol like 'GOOG' and the `<URL>` is the website's URL.

With 220 of these importdata's, I get the error:

```
"Error Loading data may take a while because of the large number of requests. Try to
reduce the amount of IMPORTHTML, IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED or IMPORTXML functions across
spreadsheets you've created."
```

The errors never go away even if I wait a long time.

See picture showing just a small section of the sheet.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xIeQ.jpg

Is there any way to fix this? I would like to put in a random delay for each of these quotes from 1-5 seconds which would fix this problem but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option, you could implement your own importdata function which would not be limited by the errors above. It would look something similar to:

```
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var responseData = response.getBlob().getDataAsString();
  var data = Utilities.parseCsv(responseData, ',');
  return data;
}
```

and add it in `Tools > Script Editor` as described in https://www.roelpeters.be/solve-loading-data-may-take-a-while-when-using-importdata-in-google-spreadsheets/

or you could try either one of these https://github.com/search?q=CryptocurrencySpreadsheetUtils instead

They implement a custom function to load the price data in bulk instead of adding 100s of importdata function calls so that you won't have any issues around that.

Comment: I marked this as the solution because it worked great.  Thank you